# API Request vs Callouts

Tags: api, callout, apex-webservice

Reference: [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/app-development-without-limits/app-development-without-limits-concurrency)

I understand that Apex callouts is a way to fetch data from external system.

I am confused as to how **API Request** differ from **Apex Callouts**.

Can someone please explain with example?

Answer (score 2):

API Requests are inbound calls, from external systems to Salesforce (for applicable limits, check [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm)). Apex callouts are outbound HTTP/Webservice calls from Apex to external systems (for the applicable callout limits and limitations: [their docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm))